# chart.js in mvc graph are not show

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

Here is chart script using chart. js  i am using chart in mvc 4 chart are not show ,
data are shore in variable but when pass data from controller to view then data or not show in chart, error is system.string[] or in labels when i put in labels then array data are show when i check in browser console but error is something like this inactive is not define . please review the code tell me where i am wrong.

```
<script>  
    var PieChartData =  
        {
            labels: [@ViewBag.b],  
            datasets: [{  
                label: 'ProductWise Sales Count',  
                backgroundColor: [  
                    "#f990a7",  
                    "#aad2ed",  
                    "#9966FF",  
                    "#99e5e5",  
                    "#f7bd83",  
                ],  
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: [@ViewBag.a]  
            }]  
        };  

        window.onload = function () {  
            var ctx1 = document.getElementById("Piecanvas").getContext("2d");  
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1,  
                {  
                    type: 'pie',  
                    data: PieChartData,  
                    options:  
                        {  
                            title:  
                            {  
                                display: true,  
                                text: "ProductWise Sales Count"  
                            },  
                            responsive: true,  
                            maintainAspectRatio: true  
                        }  
                });  
        }  
</script>
```

Now Here is Controler

```
        ICharts _ICharts;

    public ChartController()
    {
        _ICharts = new mchart();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PieChart()
    {
        try
        {
            float[] Total;
            string[] status;

            _ICharts.mTotalMember(out Total, out status);
           ViewBag.a = Total;
           ViewBag.b = status;

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }


    }
```

and this is my function

```
public class mchart : ICharts
{
    public void mTotalMember(out float [] Total, out string[] Status)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Real"].ToString()))
        {
            var productdata = con.Query<Member>("Sp_testing", null, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

            var varTotal = (from temp in productdata
                            select temp.Percentage).ToArray();

            var varStatus = (from temp in productdata
                             select temp.LeadStatus).ToArray();

            Total =  varTotal;

            Status = varStatus;
        }  
    }
}
```

Here is my function
    void mTotalMember(out float[] Total, out string[] status);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` along with `Html.Raw` method to get a javascript array from the ViewBag item. You do not need to wrap it with `[` and `]` as the result of the expression `@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.b))` will be an array.

```
var myLabels = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.b));
var myData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.a));

//Let's verify it
console.log(myLabels);  
console.log(myData);

var PieChartData =  
    {
        labels : myLabels,  
        datasets: [{  
            label: 'ProductWise Sales Count',  
            backgroundColor: [  
                "#f990a7",  
                "#aad2ed",  
                "#9966FF",  
                "#99e5e5",  
                "#f7bd83",  
            ],  
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: myData  
        }]  
    };
```